# npm install (npm update check failed)

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

$ `npm install`

Error below appeared:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                    npm update check failed                    │
│              Try running with sudo or get access              │
│             to the local update config store via              │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\blindkid\.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-BgIZWbJdP5/gavIWiFRk4JbBjp6cdr5ZB4OM9lO437w+6wY54I2cM1P9lzOUx2AC1wgDLp0wqPtvS76SyfbsYg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-BgIZWbJdP5/gavIWiFRk4JbBjp6cdr5ZB4OM9lO437w+6wY54I2cM1P9lzOUx2AC1wgDLp0wqPtvS76SyfbsYg== but got sha512-8wpp4eK9tdc+ttD5Ap23o6SbS0KsE9qwDGTHcesTP+cKvNjTKfLEhKmW5ii+xZ5d4DdVkqyYIx5Z5HXXGyQI/g==. (60830 bytes)
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated @types/testing-library__dom@7.5.0: This is a stub types definition. testing-library__dom provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\blindkid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-25T07_01_33_132Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to see how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

-Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

-Run `npm cache clean --force` and then run again `npm install`.